# Node.js http request through child process vs libcurl through C child process

Tags: node.js, libcurl

I have two options to run child process to send request to a HTTP server. One through a Node.js child process making a http request through built-in node support or through the 'request' module. Another option is to fork a C child process using libcurl api. The main http server is a Node.js server which will fork the child process. It can fork both a C executable or a Node.js executable.

Has anyone benchmarked or is aware of the performance issues involved in the two options. Both C and Node.js programming skills are available.

Comment: The original reason why node.js was written as a single threaded system is because both options perform worse than simply using the built-in http module or the request module without spawning child process. I strongly suspect that if you benchmark it child process and single threaded will be competitive up to around 1000 request per second then the single threaded code will outperform the child process.

Comment: @slebetman I think that would be too generic of a statement. Does it not depend on what the child process does? If it is simply going to forward traffic from the remote http server to the browser, thats one thing. WHat if there is CPU intensive code to be executed in the child process. Would node's single threaded system not be a bottleneck when serving 1000s of  requests? After all the node.js single-threaded "system" is merely one process from the OS point of view... to be shared resources including CPU cycles among many other peer processes. Looking forward to your comments...

Comment: As you said. 1000 "requests". Requests take 0% CPU time because 99% of the processing time is spent on the net (at the router, at the ISP's routers, at the server on the other side etc). For "requests" single threaded systems will handily beat spawning child processes. Once the requests arrive then you need to look at what processing you're doing.

Comment: Which means, if you are doing heavy processing then it should be obvious to you that nobody have benchmarked your use-case. Has anyone benchmark requests? Yes, not spawning child processes is the fastest architecture for requests. Have anyone benchmarked requests + your specific processing requirement? Obviously no because nobody has your code to benchmark except you.

Comment: @slebetman I have always been perplexed by the benchmarking involving only "requests" because every request will do some processing. So, lets say that CPU utililization for pure request processing is 1 unit and 5 units is the processing of the request (my code or whatever), then I think that the Node.js model may not be all that impressive.  Besides, is it true that internally, it does maintain a multi-threaded architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a third option, use a libcurl binding for Node.js directly: https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl

```
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl');

const { statusCode, data, headers } = await curly.get('http://www.google.com')
```

or a more verbose way (without promises):

```
const { Curl } = require('node-libcurl');

const curl = new Curl();

curl.setOpt('URL', 'www.google.com');
curl.setOpt('FOLLOWLOCATION', true);

curl.on('end', function (statusCode, data, headers) {
  console.info(statusCode);
  console.info('---');
  console.info(data.length);
  console.info('---');
  console.info(this.getInfo( 'TOTAL_TIME'));

  this.close();
});

curl.on('error', curl.close.bind(curl));
curl.perform();
```

I've done some basic benchmarks and it seems to be the fastest URL client for Node.js (but benchmarks should always be taken with a grain of salt). It supports most libcurl options.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of the package